# Не выезжает клавиатура на IOS при клике на инпут

Tags: wordpress, ios, contact-form7

Имеется сайт на Вордпресс, стандартный плагин CF7 для контактной формы. На андроид-устройствах форма работает как надо. На Iphone - при первом клике на инпутах формы клавиатура не выезжает, выезжает только на втором. Стили формы стандартные, форма вообще взята с другого сайта, тоже стандартная. Код прикладываю

```
<div class="wpcf7 js" id="wpcf7-f23-p6-o1" lang="ru-RU" dir="ltr">
    <div class="screen-reader-response">
        <p role="status" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></p> 
    </div>
        <form action="/#wpcf7-f23-p6-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form init" aria-label="Контактная форма" novalidate="novalidate" data-status="init">
            <div style="display: none;">
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="23">
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.8.3">
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="ru_RU">
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f23-p6-o1">
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="6">
                <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_posted_data_hash" value="">
            </div>
            <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden" value="Запрос звонка" type="hidden" name="subject">
            <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden inputUrl" value="https://blackfridaysale.ostupchuk.com/" type="hidden" name="url">
            <p>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="your-name">
                    <input size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required input" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Введите ваше ФИО" value="" type="text" name="your-name">
                </span><br>
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="phone">
                <input size="40" minlength="7" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-tel input" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" value="" type="tel" name="phone">
            </span><br>
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="email">
                <input size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-email input" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Введите ваш Email" value="" type="email" name="email">
            </span><br>
            <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden" value="314333" type="hidden" name="spid"><br>
            <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit has-spinner btn" type="submit" value="Отправить заявку"><span class="wpcf7-spinner"></span>
            </p><div class="wpcf7-response-output" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```